# Prove that any volume-preserving transformation on a plane can be written as a composition of (at most) three shear matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Let's say we have an endormorphism $\lambda: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, describing a volume-preserving transformation on a two-dimensional plane, so we have $\det \lambda = 1$.

I'm trying to prove that $\lambda$ can be written as composition of (at most) three shearing transformations, e.g. $\sigma_1 \circ \sigma_2 \circ \sigma_3 = \lambda$. Trivially, since shears are volume-preserving, they all have a determinant of 1, so this must also be true for their composition.

I started by looking at the transformation matrix of $\lambda$
$$ \Lambda := \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}, \quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, $$
and trying to find three shear matrices, such that their product equals $\Lambda$. I came up with

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ y & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & z \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} xy+1 & x+z+xyz \\ y & yz+1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
x=\frac{a-1}{c}, \quad y=c, \quad z=\frac{d-1}{c},
\end{equation*}

for when $c \neq 0$, and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ x & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & y \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ z & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} yz+1 & y \\ xyz+x+z & xy+1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
x=\frac{d-1}{b}, \quad y=b, \quad z=\frac{a-1}{b}.
\end{equation*}

when $b \neq 0$.

The issue is, that I can't seem to figure out a combination of three shear matrices in the event that $c = b = 0$. So I went back to the drawing board, and tried to apply the general definition of a shearing transformation
$$ \sigma = \textrm{id}_V + w\omega, \quad \textrm{where } \omega \in V^*, w \in \ker \omega, $$
but so far without success. If for example $c \neq 0$, we can pick $[\omega, w]$ as $ [e_2^*, e_1x], [e_1^*, e_2y], [e_2^*, e_3z] $, respectively.

Am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution involving three shears in the case where $c = 0 = b$. It's still possible - if we allow shears that are not constrained to an axis.

If we apply the general definition of a shear
$$ \sigma = \textrm{id}_V + w\omega, \quad \textrm{where } \omega \in V^*, w \in \ker \omega, $$
and choose
$$ \omega : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, v \mapsto v_1 + v_2, \quad w = \begin{pmatrix} -y \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \ker \omega, $$
we get the transformation matrix
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1-y & -y \\ y & 1+y \end{pmatrix}. $$
We can also verify $\det S = 1$.

Using two other "basic" shears, we get
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 - y & -y \\ y & 1 + y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ z & 1 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1-y+xy+xz-yz+xyz & x-y+xy \\ y+z+zy & y+1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
which we can solve with respect to $\Lambda$ with
$$ x = \frac{b+d-1}{d}, \quad y = d - 1, \quad z = \frac{c-d+1}{d}. $$

We know $d \neq 0$, since
$$ \det \lambda = ad - bc = 1 \quad \textrm{and} \quad a = 0 = d \implies b \neq 0 \neq c. $$

As such, combined with the two other solutions stated in my initial solution, we have covered every case with a potential solution.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: [+1] Clever ! Indeed, we aren't constrained to have the coordinate axes as shear directions !

Comment: Please, see my   Edit  2.

Comment: @JeanMarie that's super interesting, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1:** In fact, in the cases where $c=d=0$, three shears in the direction of either $x$ or $y$ axes are not enough (I have attempted the different possible cases with a Computer Algebra System, without any solution); one needs in fact four of them, in the following form,

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{x}  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & (x-1) \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \tfrac{1-x}{x} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -x & 1 \end{pmatrix} \tag{*}$$

obtained from [this page](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/shears-generate-the-special-linear-group/) which has triggered my interest, and lead with my own computer computations to the more general decomposition

$$\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & \tfrac{1}{x} \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  \tfrac{x(x-1)}{k} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac{k}{x} & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \tfrac{1-x}{k} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -k & 1 \end{pmatrix} \tag{**}$$

where $k \ne 0$ is arbitrary.

Remark: The transpose of (**) is evidently another solution.

**Edit 2:** If you look at "A course of finite groups" by Rose (available as a Google book) p. 257, you will find the theorem "The group $SL_2(q)$ is generated by its transvections" with a computational proof very close to yours. (explanation: transvections - to a certain extend - are synonymous to shears, and $q=p^n$ power of a prime).

1. There is a computation error in the result of the first product: its upper right entry should be $x+z+xyz$ instead of $x+y+xyz$.

Remark: in the second product, the lower left entry has this (correct) expression.

2. A particular case of relationship (1)

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ y & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & z \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

in the case of a pure rotation (a particular case of area preserving transformation):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos a & - \sin a\\ \sin a & \ \ \ \cos a \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & t\\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\\sin a & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & t\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

where $t \ := \ -\tan(a/2)$. See [here](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Efricke/projects/israel/paeth/rotation_by_shearing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response! (i) Thanks for catching that, that was a typo on my end. (ii) I'd assume that's true, but do the matrices in this, more general, form still count as shears? (iii) I do think I've seen this - but in our lectures we haven't used trigonometry in linear algebra yet, so I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Besides, how would it help in this case?

Comment: About (ii): you are right. where I had the head... I have to correct my answer.

Comment: Please, see my Edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you've managed to get me an idea of how to solve it using three shears, see my answer.